# Parsing "What cannot be cured must be endured"

Tags: parsing, noun-phrases, noun-clause

> What cannot be cured must be endured.

When I parse the sentence, I find that *What cannot be cured* is the NP in fused relative construction and is the subject of the sentence. *be* is the copula and *endured* is the subject complement.

If it were *That which cannot be cured must be endured* instead, the parsing would be the same except that the subject of the sentence would be the noun clause *That which cannot be cured.*

Have I got it right?

Comment: Not quite: You are right that "what cannot be cured" is an NP, but "that which cannot be cured" is also an NP, not a clause. We know it's an NP because it has the noun "that" as head.

Comment: The negative VP "cannot be cured" is the predicate in the relative clause "which cannot be cured". "Cured" is a sub clause functioning as complement of "be".

Comment: What here and that which are grammatically the same thing.

Comment: I agree. "What" means "that which". The difference is that the antecedent and the relative word are combined or 'fused' into the single word "what" -- hence the term 'fused relative construction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *endured* is a subject complement. But *That which cannot be cured* is a noun phrase.

When we say that *endured* is a subject complement, this does not tell us very much.  Is it a noun, an adjective, or a pronoun?  It is an adjective.

You have gotten part of it right.

Comment: I call it a clause, but you call it a phrase.

Comment: There's a difference: "that which cannot be cured" has the NP "that" as antecedent modified by the relative clause "which cannot be cured". It's no different to any other NP, cf. "diseases [which cannot be cured]"

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I see that you are right. I should be more careful.  It is clearly a NP.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  The contrast between the passive modal verb phrases “cannot be cured” and “must be endured” is important to the meaning of the sentence.  Some other aphorisms using this structure (antithesis) are:

> What goes around, comes around.

and

> What goes up, must come down.

In other words, I would read it closer to to the second way you give:

> (That ([which] cannot be cured)) must be endured.

However, written this way, the main and subordinate clause are not parallel.  The most common phrasing, “What cannot be cured must be endured,” strongly emphasizes the parallel structure by making the same pronoun the subject of both verb phrases, which have the same format.  I would guess that is the reason that this is the form that caught on for all three sayings.

The same structure, but with a repetition instead of a contrast, connotes fatalism or resignation instead: “The heart wants what it wants,” “Whatever will be, will be,” “It will cost what it will cost.”